# Visa application forms children- I have 2 passports and living in a 3rd country

Tags: visas

So a complex situation - I was born in South Africa and am
living in the USA on a 3 year US visa.
Our visas for the USA are in our SA Passports.
I am applying for a visa for my kids to travel with me to London. Must I list myself as a British Citizen on their application or as South African? 
Totally confusing.

Comment: Are you a British citizen?